# PHP - code optimisation - parameter "into" a function name (hum) or better method?

Tags: php

I have a function, called function($parameter) for the example. I want this function to call another function, different depending on the parameter.

My code today:

```
function($parameter)
{
    if($parameter == "A")
    {
        fctA();
    }
    elseif($parameter == "B")
    {
        fctB();
    }
    elseif($parameter == "C")
    {
        fctC();
    }
}
// etc.
// There is a long list. Really long. Imagine that goes to ZZZZZ.
```

The "inside" function is always named in the same way. For the example, fctA(), fctB()... What is inside these functions is totally different the one with another.

Could I do better than that looooong list of "if" ?
Using a variable into a function name seems impossible... but if there is a better method, I am eager to read about it! :)

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, any tips welcomed, I'm still learning!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function from your `$parameter` variable by using it in an interpolated string:

```
function ($parameter) {
  if (function_exists("fct{$parameter}")) {
    return "fct{$parameter}"();
  } else {
    return "Unknown Function: fct{$parameter}";
  }
}
```

If `$parameter` is `A`, this will call `fctA()`, if it is `B` it will call `fctB()`, and so on.

Only catch is to make sure you have a function for each possible value of `$parameter`, and they all have the same signature, such as `function fctA() { return 'A'; }`, `function fctB() { return 'B'; }`, etc etc. Thanks to [@jhmckimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084984/jhmckimm) for the `function_exists` suggestion; that is a good way to handle that.

Funcional example:

[image]

Comment: OK I had an issue (parse error with your syntax), but solved this way:
eval("return fct{$parameter}();");

Comment: @g8deve I would recommend against using eval. It can open gaping security holes in any app if not used with great care. You will probably need to store the function name in a variable and then call it: `$functionToCall = "fct" . $parameter; $functionToCall();`

Comment: oh well it's even better :) many thanks again, reaching perfection just now!

Comment: Agreed; `eval()` _can_ be unsafe; in this context `eval("return fct{X}();");`, it should be fine. What parse error did you get from my code? It works for me  (see new screenshot)

Comment: unexpected '(' on the line --> return "fct{$parameter}"();
But putting the () before the " works better ^^

Comment: @Tim https://i.ibb.co/1L6SRfk/screen.png returns me the error I said on the line I said.
But anyway I have my solution with $functionToCall = "fct".$param; and that's the perfect one :)

Comment: Sweet! I wonder if it's a PHP version thing; but that's a ponder for a different day. Glad you got it working, and `$functionToCall` is a better approach anyway so you don't have to repeat `"fct{$parameter}"` multiple times 